# str object not callable (sqlite3)

Tags: python, sql, string, python-3.x, sqlite

i keep getting the following when i run my program.

```
    look_date = "01-02-2018"
    cur.execute("SELECT item_id FROM hirers WHERE start_date=?," 
    (str(look_date),))
    -----------------------------------------------------------------
    TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: The trailing `,` in the string must be outside of the string

Comment: @MichaelButscher thank you it's working now. Can't believe I didn't see it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have probably overwritten `str` with a variable named `str`, presumably another string.

Comment: Turns out it's the comma that I put in the string by accident

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your code like this:

```
cur.execute("SELECT item_id FROM hirers WHERE start_date=?," 
((look_date,))
```